# ng if else template expression for different containers with same content

Tags: angular, angular-template

How can I use Angular's if else template condition for rendering **different** containers with the same content?

something like this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="whichContainer; then container else other_container">
   <!-- Same content for both containers -->
   content here...
</ng-container>

<ng-template #container><button>content...</button></ng-template>
<ng-template #other_container><div>content..</div></ng-template>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. If the containers must have the same content, and only one of them must be displayed at a time, what's the point in having two of them?

Comment: The containers are different. Let's say one container is a `<button>` and one is a `<div>` but both display the same content.

Comment: So, you want something like that: `<button *ngIf="theContainer === 'button'"><shared-content></shared-content></button> ... <div *ngIf="theContainer === 'div'"><shared-content></shared-content></div>`, right? Then just do that: put the shared content into a component, insert the component when it must be displayed, and display one of the containers only using an ngIf condition.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. I wanted to know if there is a way to achieve this  with the ngIf else feature...